# Réponse à "C'est super de vous revoir !"

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

> A: C'est super de vous revoir !
>
> B: ___________

Quelle serait une bonne réponse ici ?

Est-ce que "Moi aussi !" ou "C'est pareil !" sont possibles ?

Comment: Depending on the context, in English I’d be tempted to use “Ditto [for me]” or “Likewise [I’m sure]” which could lead to “Idem [pour moi]” or “[Pour] Moi itou” in French (or as Serge Gainsbourg might have put it “[Pour] Moi non plus”!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete the previous answer, some suggestions:

> Entièrement d’accord
>
> Oui c’est super (or any other synonym if you don’t want to use the same word)
>
> Oui, trop longtemps !
>
> Tu l’as dit !

Or a bit mor colloquial from where I see it, while the initial proposition isn’t much:

> Le sentiment est partagé
>
> Je n’aurais pas mieux dit

I wouldn’t use any of your propositions in that context, but if you want to use « moi aussi », you could also say:

> Moi aussi je suis très content qu’on se revoie enfin

Or any similar sentence being introduced by « moi aussi ».

I also would like to mention an expression coming from a somewhat famous French TV Game (Des chiffres et des lettres):

> Pas mieux

This may not be understood by all genererations or other Fench Speaking people who might not get the reference, but convey the meaning of you agreeing and not being able to say it better.

Comment: Some more suggestions: on the same informal tone: *et comment !*. A bit more formal: *je ne le vous fais pas dire*.

Comment: Je pense que ces réponses sont basées sur "C'est super de se revoir !". Mais ce n'était pas la phrase de départ, qui était "C'est super de vous revoir !". La différence est très grande.

Comment: @Nathan La différence n’est pas si grande... je pense que les suggestions peuvent s’appliquer à l’une comme à l’autre...

Answer (score 2):

On peut plutôt répondre:

> Pour moi aussi

Cela sous-entend "Pour moi aussi, c'est super de vous revoir". *Moi aussi* ne serait pas correct parce que cela supposerait que "moi" est le sujet du verbe de la première phrase. Par exemple, si on dit "je suis content de vous revoir", alors il est correct de répondre "moi aussi" parce que cela signifie "moi aussi, je suis content de vous revoir".

"C'est pareil" n'est pas approprié et pourrait être compris comme "ça ne fait pas de différence pour moi". Il existe l'adverbe *pareillement*, mais il signifie "à vous aussi", et il est utilisé comme réponse à "bonne journée", "bonne soirée", etc.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, an answer is not required. It's just an exclamation. You can share the joy, and not answer a word, or say that you share it (in the way you want), or switch to another subject.
Or you may not be happy to see this person, and retaliate that you dont find it so "super" ..

Answer (score 2):

For me, the best response is:

"Ça me fait plaisir aussi (de vous revoir)".

You can obviously skip the part in the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

As already replied, none of your attempts work.

There are a gazillion possible replies. Here is one expressing the "mee too", "same for me" idea:

> *Toi aussi, c'est super de te revoir !*

or, depending on who you are replying to:

> *Vous aussi, c'est super de vous revoir !*